# Speed up Hibernate EntityManager initialization

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm using the Hibernate JPA provider. It seems like it takes a tremendous amount of time (over 3 seconds) just loading the @Entity annotated classes and building various type trees and query trees. Is there any way to speed this up? It really makes unit tests a downer, even though it just happens once.

I already turned off schema validation and update. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using EntityManagerFactory as static? PS.: 3 seconds for using hibernate is not bad at all.

Comment: I am. But if I'm trying to debug an issue and repeatedly run a unit test I have to wait 3-4 seconds to see if my code fixed the issue. If I'm running the full suite, it's not so bad, but my unit tests are very fast. Hibernate creating its Entity Manager Factory takes longer than almost all the tests combined!

Comment: if you are not using Hibernate annotations, make a try with eclipseLink. I use both and EclipseLink is a little bit faster.